# Spring security auto login when server start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working with Spring boot back end with Spring Security.
In development mode, I would like to be automatically logged in when the server starts.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to define another implementation of certain beans that  always pass the authentication and return a hardcoded user information of the login user. Then use [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.0-SNAPSHOT/core/beans/environment.html#beans-definition-profiles-java) feature to activate these implementations only for the development.

What these beans are depends on your authentication process. As you do not provide any information about it , I cannot tell you what are they.